# How to map an array of objects to an array of values by key

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the message by key-word in the json structure. For example, the json structure is:

`[{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}`

Now I want to get all the message and put them into an arrary. How to implement this in javascript? Thanks

Comment: `var res = data.map( v => v.message )`

Comment: awesome comment , 37 characters that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` or loop over the array and push the message to the array.

```js
var a = [{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}];

var b = a.map(function(obj){
   return obj.message;
});

console.log(b);
```

Comment: "Not bad code". Why do you need an `i` variable what is unused to? Try arrow function instead/

Comment: @HappyCoding, I prefer sticking with a code that works for most browsers. ES6 is very new--I know it's exciting--but you need to either use a compiler like Babel or lots of polyfills. :) OP seems to be new to JavaScript, and still making their first steps. Don't rush into ES6 yet.

Comment: @Adam Azad Thanks you so much, Adam! But I am just confusing what does the obj mean here?

Comment: @XiufenXu, `obj` is the object like`{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }` for instance. It's a mere variable referring to the current object in the array. You can change it with any letter you want, but the shorter, the better.

Comment: @Adam Azad Got you! Very clear explanation. Thank you so much

Comment: @XiufenXu, you're welcomed :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var json = [{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}];
var arr = [];
for(i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
 arr.push(json[i].message);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers applies everywhere

```
var initialArray = [{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}]
var newArray = [];
for(i=0;i<initialArray.length;i++){
  newArray.push(initialArray[i].message)
}
console.log(newArray)
```

or shorter way to write above code

```
var initialArray = [{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}],
newArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) newArray.push(initialArray[i].message);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method with [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
var data=[{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}];

var res = data.map(v => v.message);

console.log(res);
```

---

With traditional function instead of arrow function.

```js
var data=[{ _id: 123, message: 'hello', username: '1' }, { _id: 456, message: 'world', username: '2'}];

var res = data.map(function(v){
   return  v.message;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use JsonPath:
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

```
var messages = jsonPath(yourArray, "$..message");
```

In my opinion the easiest ways to find stuff in json.